# IntegrityError at /post/new/ NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_post.author_id

Tags: python, django

Iam trying to learn django but this thing is stopping me from doing that
this is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Post
# Create your views here.
 
def home(request):
    context = {
        'posts' : Post.objects.all
    }
    return render(request,'blog/home.html',context)
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    # <app>/<model><viewtype>.html
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title','content']
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title','content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False
class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin,CreateView):
    #LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin,DeleteView
    #LoginRequiredMixin, AuthorMixin, ListView
    model = Post
    success_url = '/'
    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        else:
            return False
def about(request):
    return render(request,'blog/about.html',{'title':'About'})
```

this is my models.py in app directory:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

Please help me to solve this bug Iam a self taught web developer and Please give me some advice to learn django framework in python this is really stopping me from achiving my goals and this is lagging my valuable time

Comment: Please [edit] and add the code for your model `Post` to the question.

Comment: Yes I have added it

Comment: When is the error occuring?

Comment: When I try to to upload a post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `PostCreateView` creates instances of `Post` and you have set `fields = ['title','content']` meaning only these fields would show up in the form. But you have a field `author` which is non-nullable and without a default, hence you need to set a value for this field too. If you want to set it to the current logged in user you can override the `form_valid` method of the form and do it there (You already seem to be doing this in `PostUpdateView`?):

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title','content']
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```